# Linked List method that removes the node before the node having the given node value

Tags: java, linked-list

This is my method to  remove the node before the node having the given node value, but it is not work, how can i do. For example, 1 to 5, put RemoveBefore(3), it will remove 4.

```
public void RemoveBefore(int nodeValue) 
{
    Node curr = start;  

    while (curr != null) 
    {
        Node next = curr.next; 

        if (next!= null && next.nodeValue == nodeValue) 
        {                   
            curr= next.next;                
            return;
        }
        curr = curr.next;

    }
}
```

Comment: If you wrote this code you know enough to answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the value of `curr` like you did:

```
curr= next.next;
```

will make no changes to the list itself because `curr` is a just a local reference, changing the reference will not change the content pointed by it.

If you want your changes to have effect you need to modify the content of the object pointed by the reference.

In your case the situation is the following:

```
... -> prev -> curr -> next -> next.next -> ...
```

If `next` has your value, you want `prev` to point directly to `next`, in fact removing `curr` from the list like so:

```
... -> prev -> next -> next.next -> ...
```

This means you want to change `prev` so it point to `next` instead of `curr`.

So in your code you need to introduce the `prev` variable and also manage the special case when the node to remove is the start itself:

```
startNode -> node2 -> node3 -> ...
```

has to become:

```
node2 (the new start node) -> node3 -> ...
```

This is how I would modify the code:

```
public void RemoveBefore(int nodeValue) 
{
    Node curr = start;  
    Node previous = null;

    while (curr != null) 
    {
        Node next = curr.next; 

        if (next!= null && next.nodeValue == nodeValue) 
        {                   
            if( previous == null) {
                start = next;         // change directly the start of the list
            } else {
                previous.next = next; // point to next instead of curr   
            }
            return;
        }
        previous = curr;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: but when i changed to that, nothing happen when i run.

Comment: yes I corrected my answer